# Chrome extension that shows if page has been visited before. Does it exist? If not, would it be hard to make?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I have been manually sending my resume to employers and wanted to know whether there is a Chrome extension that shows when I have visited a page before. This is to avoid sending my resume twice to the same company. I looked all over for one and couldn't find anything.

What I wanted would be just a basic icon that is grayed out if this is the first time you visit the page according to your browser history and lights up otherwise.

Does it exist? If not, would it be hard to make? I know a little C++ and understand algorithms in general, but have no other knowledge regarding extensions at all.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We also could not find a Chrome Extension that shows if a web page has been visited before by us so we have created a free one for you:


https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/have-i-visited-this-page/fidkmjollhlgbbinbgbgajcejglhhhkd


Please let us know what modifications you may require and we'll try to update it for you.


Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it exists, but to solve this problem you can just build a simple chrome extension (yes it's easy if you want to know), [chrome.history Api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history) will help you do the trick, use chrome.history.search and change icon color following the result.

Comment: We also could not find a Chrome Extension that shows if a web page has been visited before by us so we have created a free one for you: chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/have-i-visited-this-page/… Please let us know what modifications you may require and we'll try to update it for you. Many thanks

Comment: @twiz911 The link is broken. I really want your extension!!

Comment: @twiz911 I think I found your extension. It is not really what I am looking for - I would like something that, when I hover over a link, indicates that I have visited it before. C.f., the FIrefox extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-status-redux/ (but it would be even better if the indication appeared next to the mouse pointer rather than in the browser window's status bar).

Comment: @twiz911 Or maybe add a symbol next to a link indicating its visited status.

Comment: @d-b thanks for your feedback. I will add your feature request to the extension backlog. I appreciate your support of my development.